# JavaScript: Moment diff function giving incorrect days difference

Tags: javascript, momentjs, angular-moment

```
var firstDate=moment('Sat Jul 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)');
var secondDate=moment('Fri Jul 29 2016 10:56:39 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)');

console.log(firstDate.diff(secondDate,'days'));
```

Expected Output: 1

Actual Output: -0

Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: You should expect -1 since *secondDate* is before *firstDate*.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the second argument as `true` to diff method to prevent moment from rounding the difference to nearest zero.

```
firstDate.diff(secondDate,'days', true)
```